# Cache-Misses in OSU Unidirectional Bandwidth Test

Tags: caching, mpi, bandwidth, intel-mpi

We are measuring the cache-misses in `MPI_Isend()+MPI_Waitall()` at the Sender and `MPI_Irecv()+MPI_Waitall()` at the receiver for the OSU unidrectional bandwidth benchmark. Suprisingly, the cache-misses at `8KB` message size exceed that at the `16KB` message size when using `Intel MPI 2017.4` and `Intel compiler 2017.4`. We capture cache-misses using the profiler TAU. Below are some graphs which capture this strange behaviour:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

We have ruled out the effect of Eager-Rendezvous switchover as the default `I_MPI_EAGER_THRESHOLD` is `256 KB` and the re-allocation of pre-registered buffers as the message size is less than the default size of pre-registered buffers (which is around 23.5 KB for Intel MPI).

Any insight will be valuable. Thanks !

**Addition 1**: The communication is between nodes which are connected with Intel OPA having a maximum bandwidth of `100 Gbits/sec`.

**Addition 2**: We *suspect* that the default `Path MTU size of 8 KB` for Intel OPA has "something" to do with it but still the questions remains as to why cache-misses for a message of size 16 KB is less than that at 8 KB.

Comment: Are the two processes communicating within a node or between nodes?

Comment: @DavidHenty: My apologies for the late reply. The two processes are communicating between nodes.

Comment: OK - in that case I don't understand what's going on! The thresholds for on-node transfers seem to be controlled independently of I_MPI_EAGER_THRESHOLD - see https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/tuning-the-intel-mpi-library-advanced-techniques.html - but that's not relevant for your use case.

Comment: @DavidHenty: No problem. I thank you for your time and effort. Best regards, Gaurav